# Node Pega valores nulos do form html e nao consegue cadastrar no banco mysql!

Tags: javascript, node.js

HTML

```
<form id="registerForm" method="post" action="/register">
    <div id="user">
        <label for="username">Nome de usuário:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password">Senha:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Registrar" id="button">
    </div>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    document.getElementById('registerForm').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value;

  if (!username || !password) {
      alert('Preencha todos os campos');
      return;
  }

  fetch('/register', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
      alert(data.message);
  })
  .catch(error => {
      console.error('Erro:', error);
  });
});
```

NODE

```
  app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  if (!username || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Preencha todos os campos' });
  }

  // const connection = mysql.createConnection(dbConfig);

  // Conecte-se ao banco de dados
  connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Erro na conexão ao banco de dados:', err);
      return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Erro no registro' });
    }

    const insereNovoUsuario = 'INSERT INTO usuarios (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)';
    connection.query(insereNovoUsuario, [username, password], (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Erro ao inserir o novo usuário no banco de dados:', err);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Erro no registro' });
      }
      
      connection.end();
      return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Registrado com sucesso' });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: em que lugar declarou a utilização do middleware json? Ex.: `app.use(express.json());`

Comment: declarei depois da conexão com o banco e antes dos app.get

Comment: Executei o código disponibilizado e não é possível reproduzir o problema. Ao clicar no botão `Registrar`, as ações são executadas com sucesso, os dados (json) aparecem no backend, e o alert com a mensagem `Registrado com sucesso`, aparece normalmente. O código completo implementado por mim e diponível em meu github pessoal pode ser acessado [aqui](https://github.com/danizavtz/staticwebpageform).

Answer (score -2):

Utilizando o código fornecido, não foi possível reproduzir o problema descrito acima.

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`<html lang="pt-br">

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <main>
            <form id="registerForm" method="post" action="/register">
                <div id="user">
                    <label for="username">Nome de usuário:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="password">Senha:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Registrar" id="button">
                </div>
            </form>
        </main>
    </body>
    
    </html>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('registerForm').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
    
            const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
            const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    
            if (!username || !password) {
                alert('Preencha todos os campos');
                return;
            }
    
            fetch('/register', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    alert(data.message);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Erro:', error);
                });
        });
    </script>`);
});
app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    if (!username || !password) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Preencha todos os campos' });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Registrado com sucesso' });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port);
console.log(`Microsservice uploader listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
```